# Unable to create requested service (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to write a Hibernate configuration file. But this line:

```
sessionFactory = configuration.configure(new File("/opt/webserver/hibernate-cfg/hibernate.cfg.xml")).buildSessionFactory();
```

throws:

```
[4/7/21 18:20:49:498 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
[4/7/21 18:20:49:499 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:500 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:500 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:501 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:501 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:502 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:502 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:502 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:181)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:503 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:503 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:504 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:411)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:504 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:80)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:504 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:707)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:504 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:505 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at com.provisioning.database.db.DeviceStorageHibernate.init(DeviceLockingHibernate.java:51)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:505 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at com.provisioning.database.db.DeviceStorageHibernate.<init>(DeviceLockingHibernate.java:33)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:505 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at com.provisioning.gtc.RequestTargetProcessor.getTargetLock(RequestTargetProcessor.java:232)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:505 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at com.provisioning.gtc.RequestTargetProcessor.run(RequestTargetProcessor.java:69)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:506 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling Driver#connect
[4/7/21 18:20:49:507 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:507 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:107)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:508 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:110)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:508 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:508 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:57)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:509 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at 
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:448)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:509 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:314)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:510 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:290)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:510 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:492)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:511 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:99)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:511 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:511 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:512 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:512 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:514 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:179)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:515 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:107)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:516 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:516 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:517 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:517 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  ... 17 more
[4/7/21 18:20:49:517 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

[4/7/21 18:20:49:518 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:519 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:519 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:520 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:675)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:520 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:448)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:521 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:521 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:522 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:383)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:522 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:776)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:522 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:432)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:523 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:523 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:523 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:524 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:524 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
[4/7/21 18:20:49:524 IST] 000000e0 SystemErr     R  ... 32 more
```

My configuration XML looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        
        <property name = "hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        
        <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@DB_HOSTNAME:1521:DB_SID</property>
        
        <property name="username">some_username</property>

        <property name="connection.password">some_password</property>
        
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        
        <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
        <mapping class = "com.database.objects.dao.DeviceStorageDAO"/>
        
    </session-factory>
    
</hibernate-configuration>
```

First for all I did not see a place where i can put the DB schema name anywhere. And second my DB is 11g, from all Googling I see 10g is the one to use in Dialect. Is that correct?

From what I read, this is the configuration failing to connect to the DB. But i don't know why, all the info is correct.

Any help on this would be helpful.

If its of any use I am using hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha7.jar, hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar and hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar in my application.

Comment: Use Hibernate 5.4.30.Final instead. Apart from that, yes, the Oracle10gDialect is fine.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace, it probably contains the root cause

Comment: @Guillaume I have added the full stack trace.

Comment: Did you post the entire thing? It looks like the end is missing. You need to look for "caused by...", here it says Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling Driver#connect so for some reasone it cannot connect. There might be an error in the password, the URL etc.

Comment: @Guillaume Oh sorry! Yeah. There was more lines below. In my rush to upload the stacktrace, I just didn't bother scrolling down. It says invalid username/password. Which is baffling, coz I am sure it is correct. I even tested the pair in SQLDeveloper. My only doubt is is the URL, in the i put the SID with `:`, some examples say to use a `/`.

Comment: Just to add My Oracle DB is 11.2.0.4.0 and I am using ojdb6.jar and on JDK1.8.